# How to 'burn' a subtitle track onto an mp4 video file

Tags: video-editing, video-subtitles

I would like to make a subtitle file to be a part of an mp4 video file, so that I don't have to deal with two separate files.

I imagine two ways:

- Make the subtitle an intrinsic part of the video. This will require video re-encoding.
- Make the subtitle a separate stream, but still embedded in the same video file. This is far more preferable, especially because I can disable it (unlike the other approach), or even play with the font type/size.

How do I do things the 2nd way? It would also be kool to know how the 1st approach works.

Comment: I haven't worked it out yet, but I'm very interested... It seems that the mp4 (MPEG-4) container can handle seperate emedded suptitle streams.. so (to me) that would be the way to go.. If you you hard-graft the subtitles into the video itself, you need to re-encode the video and they are embedded forever... The only advantage of hard-"coded" subtitles is that the video player doesn't need to be mp4-subtitle-stream aware...  It's quite straight forward to hard encode an AVI , but I haven't had the need to use sutitle streams yet (yet :). Where is the format of your subtitles?

Comment: @fred My subtitle file ends with `.srt`, and Nautilus tells me the format is SubRip subtitles (application/x-subrip).

Answer (score 9):

The [Matroska (mkv) container format](http://www.matroska.org/) supports text-based subtitles embedded as a separate stream into the file.

You could use [mkvmerge](http://www.bunkus.org/videotools/mkvtoolnix/doc/mkvmerge.html) to remux the file to .mkv and include the subtitles in the output, which you can enable/disable when playing the video. Note that this method will NOT re-encode the video or audio, it's just putting the same data into a different container format, so it will not decrease the quality of the video.

```
mkvmerge -o output.mkv video.mp4 subtitles.srt
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, and so fast I thought it crashed on start!

Comment: If you don't have it installed, `sudo apt install mkvtoolnix`

Answer (score 3):

In a package called *`gpac`*, there is a CLI utility called *`MP4Box`*

Here is an example of what worked for me..

```
MP4Box  -add ~/file.noaudio.mp4 \
        -add ~/file.mp3 \
        -add ~/file.srt \
             ~/file.MP4Box.mp4
```

I used a video-only and audio-only, but it will surely(?) work with a normal audio+video "movie" ....  It's very late so I'll just leave it at that...

Note: The subtitles works in Totem, but not in SMPlayer...

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
mencoder -oac copy -ovc copy -sub subs.srt video.mp4 -o new_video.mp4
```

Comment: That doesn't work. It results in mangled audio and video, and the video is truncated (initial file is ~1.6GB and resulting file is ~200MB). I use mencoder 1.0-rc3.

Comment: I have an mp4 file and an srt. But with these arguments the subtitle does not appear on the resulting file. :(

Comment: Looked exactly what I was looking for. Tried it with a WebM video (VP8 video track, VORBIS audio track) and got a broken video as a result. Shame. :\